# How do I change the "Know More" text and link in Corporate Plus wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, customization

I'm using a theme called "Corporate Plus" on WordPress.

The problem is, I want to edit a button in the front page which says "Know More", an `<a>` element with '#' as a link.

They give no option for editing this in the theme options, and I cannot find any instance of 'know more' in the entire theme folder.

If I open up the site and inspect element, the CSS for the item is shown to be on the file path 'index(72)' > 72nd line of the index file.

I then open up 'view source' and find that sure enough, on line 72, the CSS for the item is written there.

However, the text 'know more' is way further down the page file, and there is no file in the theme folder that seems to have a 'know more' text within it.

How does this happen?

How do I change the 'know more' text?

Note: Yes I'm using the free version, that's why I ask the question. So don't tell me to upgrade. Upgrading gives the option in the 'customize' section of the dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your theme customization, you could try to add this in `function.php` file located in your active child theme or theme:

```
function custom_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return '<a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . __("Your Read More Link Text", "your_theme_slug") . '</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'custom_excerpt_more' );
```

[WP codex: Customizing the Read More](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More)

Answer (score 1):

Find corporate-plus/acmethemes/hooks/slider-selection.php. Go to about line 109 and change this code:

"Know More" - change to whatever you want.
Change a href="" to a href="your-link"