# String integration functions.php WPML

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

Hey guys am trying to translate the last words of my WP Site. The problem is the "Read More" will not be translated. I tried on WPML to find a solutin but every time i get an error 500 or only a text output that does not work.

```
/* Modify the WordPress read more link
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
function modify_read_more_link() {
return '... <a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Read More</a>';
}

//* Modify the Genesis content limit read more link
add_filter( 'get_the_content_more_link', 'matchstick_more_link' );
function matchstick_more_link() {
    return '... <a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Read More</a>';
}

function matchstick_custom_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '... <a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Read More</a>';
}
```

and i should insert

```
<?php _e( 'Read Me', 'text-domain' ); ?>
```

Can anyone tell me what am doing wrong because with this Code Snipet it is not working

Comment: read me or read more?! Also check [Customizing read more](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More)

Comment: [How do I change the “Know More” text…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37506009/how-do-i-change-the-know-more-text-and-link-in-corporate-plus-wordpress-theme) similar for `Read more` text