# WordPress Button-on-Hompage Issue | Simple Fix? (Can't use Customizer ... PHP edit?)

Tags: php, wordpress, button

(Total newbie here and not a web developer by any means. Thought I'd try and ask since my Google queries typically bring me to this site anyway.)

I am using a WordPress theme, Corporate Plus. The button on the homepage will not take whatever link I input through the Customizer.

Preview of what I'm seeing (the "Let's Get Started" button): http://ruleyourcompetition.com/?customize_changeset_uuid=105d9013-cf7a-4d54-9808-0039f71eb423

Per [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37506009/how-do-i-change-the-know-more-text-and-link-in-corporate-plus-wordpress-theme) I found here on StackOverflow, it seems like I can edit the function.php file with:

```
function custom_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return '<a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . __("Your Read More Link Text", "your_theme_slug") . '</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'custom_excerpt_more' );
```

However, I'm not sure what changes to the above code I might need to make, if this is the recommended way to go about it. I tried the simpler fix mentioned in the replies on that other thread, but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Trying not to break the site. Can anyone recommend advice?

Thank you!

Comment: That particular code is filtering the "Read More" link text. This is not what you're looking for. Read More is created when you insert a Read More tag into a post/page copy block to define where you want your excerpt to end. You're likely going to need to make the change to that button inside the page you're editing.

Comment: Here's a couple links to learn about the read more tag and the filter you posted. https://en.support.wordpress.com/more-tag/ and https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_more.

Comment: Thanks @AndyWarren ... this is done through the Customizer option, so it's not a standard WP page, unfortunately. I'm able to use shortcodes and inline css okay on other pages.

Looks like that means what I saw on the other thread wasn't accurate. Argh.

Since this is done on the homepage, my suspicion is I need to edit a .php file. But I have messed around one too many times in the past in these files and screwed things up. Thus, me posting here!